# Retrieve data from a form using jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, mysql, forms

I'm trying to get information from a form and passing it to mysql. Here is my method:

```
var form = [];

$("input").each(function(){
var id = $(this).attr("name");
var value = $(this).val();
alert(id);

var item = {};
item ["name"] = id;
item ["value"] = value;

form.push(item);        
});

return JSON.stringify(form);
```

The problem is when i try to get the checked and unchecked values from the radio buttons. The query string that I want to pass to mysql outputs like this:

`insert into contatos (nome, rua, sexo, sexo, ncasa, civil, civil, civil, bairro, aniversario, cidade, rg, cpf, usuario, telefone, senha, email, confirmasenha) values ('', '', 'M', 'F', '', 'S', 'C', 'D', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')`

The fields "sexo" and "civil" are repeating. How do I make the input to read the radio buttons only 1 time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are iterating over each text field and if you have 3 radio button you are pushing all 3 values to array so  I took 2 radio fields sexo and civil outside loop so It will be pushed only 1 time and not be repeated.

```
$("input").each(function(){



if(id!='sexo' || id!='civil'){

     var id = $(this).attr("name");
     var value = $(this).val();

     var item = {};
    item ["name"] = id;
    item ["value"] = value;

    form.push(item);

}


});

 var value1 =$('input:radio[name=sexo]:checked').val();
 var value2 =$('input:radio[name=civil]:checked').val();

    var item = {};
    item ["name"] = "sexo";
    item ["value"] = value1;

    form.push(item);

    var item = {};
    item ["name"] = "civil";
    item ["value"] = value2;

    form.push(item);


return JSON.stringify(form);
```

Comment: This works fine, but dont resolve my problem. I want to find a way that the fields "sexo" and "civil" dont repeat

Comment: I think that may be because you are iterating over each text field and if you have 3 radio button you are pushing all 3 values to array so In the above answer I took 2 radio fields sexo and civil outside loop so It will be pushed only 1 time and not be repeated

Answer (score 0):

If you call `serializeArray` on a jQuery form element you'll get an array of objects, similar to the one you are creating, and will avoid duplicates:

```
$('form').serializeArray();
```

will return:

```
[
  {
    name: "firstfield",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "secondfield",
    value: "2"
  }
]
```